# SQL query to retrieve values that don't have a specific value

Tags: mysql, database, select

I tried to write a query that would return each of the 1 matkul values worth E with conditions on the matkul value not having a value of A, AB, B, BC, C, D.

| ID | id_matkul | nilai |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a101 | E |
| 2 | a101 | E |
| 3 | a102 | A |
| 4 | a102 | E |
| 5 | a102 | E |
| 6 | a103 | BC |
| 7 | a103 | E |
| 8 | a104 | B |
| 9 | a104 | E |
| 10 | a104 | E |

Comment: `WHERE ... NOT IN (...)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform a conditional query you can use the SQL `NOT` operator. In this example where you have multiple conditionals that must be satisfied it may make more sense to use the `NOT IN` operator with a list of values that must be satisfied.

### Examples

##### NOT

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT id = 'A' AND NOT id = 'B';`

More examples - [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

##### NOT IN

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN ('A', 'B');`

More examples - [W3Resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php)

Also if depending on how you determined which values you need to exclude (if you query to find them for example) you can either nest the Not In with a query or take a look at this stack overflow solution - [Not-in-vs-Not-Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)